# Entity Framework Model different then my business Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, ado.net

I have a business model different then my Entity model.

Example:  I have two tables say Client and Address and each table shares the same type of data flags.

**Client Table** 
ClientID
FirstName
LastName
CreateBY
CreateDate
Hidden
Deleted
Active

**Address Table**
Address1
Address2
City
State
Zipcode
CreateBY
CreateDate
Hidden
Deleted
Active

I have the same properties in both tables and both Class objects the client class object and the Address class object created from the entity frame work.

CreateBY
CreateDate
Hidden
Deleted
Active

What I want to do is split these properties up into their own class so that I could set them with a method. How could I do this and still use the update model from database on the entity?

Comment: You want a common database table or just a common business model?

Comment: If they're not in their own table then do they really need to be in their own class?  Could you not just make them members of an interface and then use partial classes to make each of your entity classes implement that interface?

Comment: Usually what I would do is just have a separate class for these flags and include that class as a property within the Client class or Address class.  I am not sure what to do using this entity.